# Get data that input in Datastore via web app to Android

Tags: java, android, web-applications, google-cloud-endpoints, datastore

I'm new at Google app engine. I want to use Android application to login with username, this username is data that the user pushes into datastore via Web application (android and web app use same datastore)

But I can't login with username and password in the datastore, I get an error code when I try to login in android:

```
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968): {
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968):   "code" : 503,
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968):   "errors" : [ {
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968):     "domain" : "global",
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968):     "message" : "",
12-24 18:26:09.432: W/System.err(968):     "reason" : "backendError"
12-24 18:26:09.442: W/System.err(968):   } ],
12-24 18:26:09.442: W/System.err(968):   "message" : ""
12-24 18:26:09.442: W/System.err(968): }
12-24 18:26:09.442: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
12-24 18:26:09.442: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
12-24 18:26:09.452: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
12-24 18:26:09.452: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1045)
12-24 18:26:09.452: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
12-24 18:26:09.452: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
12-24 18:26:09.452: W/System.err(968):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
12-24 18:26:09.462: W/System.err(968):  at com.example.newand2_2.MainActivity$EndpointsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:178)
12-24 18:26:09.462: W/System.err(968):  at com.example.newand2_2.MainActivity$EndpointsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-24 18:26:09.462: W/System.err(968):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-24 18:26:09.462: W/System.err(968):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-24 18:26:09.472: W/System.err(968):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-24 18:26:09.472: W/System.err(968):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-24 18:26:09.472: W/System.err(968):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-24 18:26:09.482: W/System.err(968):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-24 18:26:09.482: W/System.err(968):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

and this is my code

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {
          CollectionResponseUser listusr;


            @Override
            protected User doInBackground(String... params) {

                username1 =params[0];
                password1 =params[1];


                System.out.println("doInBackground ---  username1 = "+username1);
                System.out.println("doInBackground ---  password1 = "+password1);


                Userendpoint.Builder  endpointBuilder = new Userendpoint.Builder(
                  AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                  new JacksonFactory(),
                  new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                  public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
                  });
              Userendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
          endpointBuilder).build();
              System.out.println("0");
          try {

              result = endpoint.getUser(username1).execute();
              System.out.println("1");


              listusr = endpoint.listUser().execute();


              if(result!=null)
              {
                  System.out.println("2");
                if(result.getEmail().equals(username1) && result.getPassword().equals(password1)){

                  listUsername=result.getEmail();
                  listPassword=result.getPassword();
                  System.out.println("result --- user "+listUsername);
                  System.out.println("result--- pass "+listPassword);

                  checkLogin = 1;

                }

                else
                {   System.out.println("Not Match");
                    checkLogin = 0;
                    result =null;
                    }
              }

              else{
                  System.out.println("Accout NULL");
                    checkLogin = 0;
                    result =null;
              }

          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("WTF");
              checkLogin = 0;
              result =null;
            e.printStackTrace();
          }


        return result; 
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(User getResult) {
                getResult = result; 

                System.out.println("onPUser --- user "+onPUser);
                  System.out.println("onPPass--- pass "+onPPass);
                  if(checkLogin==1 && (getResult!=null))
                  {  
                      onPUser = getResult.getEmail();
                        onPPass =getResult.getPassword();

                      Intent showAllAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class); 
                      showAllAct.putExtra("onPUser", username);
                        showAllAct.putExtra("onPPass", password);

                        startActivity(showAllAct);
                  }
                  else if(checkLogin==0)
                  {

                      builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                      builder1.setMessage("Incorrect Username or Password");
                      builder1.setCancelable(false);
                      builder1.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                                 ed_usernameIn.setText("");
                                ed_passwordIn.setText("");
                            }
                         });

                        builder1.show();          
                  }
            return;

        }

      }
}
```

I don't know it include clientId ,I don't understand about it,so I don't use it.

How to solve that?